# Why a norm distribution does not plot a line on stats.probplot()?

Tags: python, plot, data-cleaning, feature-engineering, scipy.stats

The problem is with the resultant graph of function `scipy.stats.probplot()`.
Samples from a normal distribution doesn't produce a line as expected.

I am trying to normalize some data using graphs as guidance.

However, after some strange results showing that zscore and log transformations were having no effect, I started looking for something wrong.

So, I built a graph using synthetic values that has a norm distribution and the resultant graph seems very awkward.

Here is the steps to reproduce the array and the graph:

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

mu = 0
variance = 1
sigma = math.sqrt(variance)
x = np.linspace(mu - 3*sigma, mu + 3*sigma, 100)
norm = stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma)

plt.plot(x, norm)
plt.show()
_ = stats.probplot(norm, plot=plt, sparams=(0, 1))
plt.show()
```

Distribution curve:

[image: Distribution curve]

Probability plot:

[image: Probability plot]

Comment: I don't see the problem here. The distribution curve looks like a standard normal probability density function and the probplot looks like a standard normal cumulative distribution function. Have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: Look at this notebook:
https://www.kaggle.com/code/serigne/stacked-regressions-top-4-on-leaderboard
There, the author plotted the probabilities of the normalized 'SalesPrice' and the probabilites formed a straight line, not a curve like my data which also has a normal distribution.

Comment: Your synthesized data aren't normally distributed, they are uniformly distributed, this is what `numpy.linspace()` does. You can visualize this by adding `seaborn.distplot(x, fit=scipy.stats.norm)`. Try synthesizing your data with `numpy.random.normal()`, this is its specific purpose. When I use `numpy.random.normal()` and plug it into the code in the kaggle link, I get figures which look like those in the kaggle link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your synthesized data aren't normally distributed, they are uniformly distributed, this is what `numpy.linspace()` does. You can visualize this by adding `seaborn.distplot(x, fit=scipy.stats.norm)`.

```py
import math

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import seaborn as sns


mu = 0
variance = 1
sigma = math.sqrt(variance)
x = np.linspace(mu - 3*sigma, mu + 3*sigma, 100)
y = stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma)

sns.distplot(y, fit=stats.norm)
fig = plt.figure()
res = stats.probplot(y, plot=plt, sparams=(0, 1))
plt.show()
```

Try synthesizing your data with `numpy.random.normal()`. This will give you normally distributed data.

```py
import math

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import seaborn as sns


mu = 0
variance = 1
sigma = math.sqrt(variance)
x = np.random.normal(loc=mu, scale=sigma, size=100)

sns.distplot(x, fit=stats.norm)
fig = plt.figure()
res = stats.probplot(x, plot=plt, sparams=(0, 1))
plt.show()
```